# regex filtering repeatating items with numerics

Tags: python, regex

I have list of items as below

```
list1=['test_input_1','test_input_2','test_input_3','test_input_10','test_input_11']
```

I need the following output- test_input_1

code

```
for each in list1:
    string1 = each
    pattern = r'test_.*[1].*'
    match = re.search(pattern,string1)
    if match:
        print 'matched=', match.group()

Output-
matched= test_input_1
matched= test_input_10
matched= test_input_11

Expected Output-
matched= test_input_1
```

Also, what is the difference between 'r' & 'u' before the pattern?

Comment: Try pattern `r'^test_input_1$'`, although I don't understand why not just using string comparison. Can you explain more thoroughly what kind of patterns do you want to accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what your use-case is, or what you are trying to do.. The code you have written does exactly what it is supposed to do....

It seems you do not understand regular expressions correctly...

I will break down `test_.*[1].*` for you...

- `test_` : just simply wants to find "test_" in the text.
- `.*`    : this means any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`) which means it can be 0 as well.
- `[1]`   : this means any character in the group, so in this case, the only character given is `1`.
- `.*`    : this means any character (`.`) any number of times (`*`) which means it can be 0 as well. (again)

So it makes sense that you are getting `test_input_1`, `test_input_10`, and `test_input_11` since they all follow this pattern.

---

Since you only want to catch the pattern that matches `test_input_1` it makes no sense to use regular expressions... you can just compare each string in the list to `test_input_1`.

```
for item in list1:
    if item == 'test_input_1':
        # you found it!
        print ("Found: test_input_1")
```

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with this....

Maybe something like this helps you more:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(list1):
    if item == 'test_input_1':
        print ('Found "test_input_1" at index %s' % idx)
```

---

But if you need to do the same idea in regular expressions, then something like this:

```
import re

def find_pattern(pattern, lst):
    regex = re.compile(pattern)
    for idx, item in enumerate(lst):
        match = regex.match(item)
        if not match:
            continue
        yield match.group(1), idx

list1=['test_input_1','test_input_2','test_input_3','test_input_10','test_input_11']
pat = r'(test_.*_1)\b'

for r in find_pattern(pat, list1):
    print 'found %s at index %s' % r

>>> 
found test_input_1 at index 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your input..As mentioned, I don'

Comment: Thanks for your inputs..I changed the logic, so I dont need it anymore..Your tips were useful..